# how we export csv file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

when we using this code then it downloads the csv file but when I open the downloaded file it is just an empty excel sheet, any idea?

controller:     function create_csv()
    {

```
$this->load->model('Home');
$this->load->dbutil();
$this->load->helper('csv');
$report = $this->Home->print_report();
$delimiter = ",";
$newline = "\r\n";
$new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($report, $delimiter, $newline);
write_file( 'application/third_party/file.csv', $new_report);
redirect('Welcome/index');
 }
```

we have make an csv_helper.php file

Comment: Provide the print_r() text in your question to

Answer (score 0):

use this code before print_r() function 
       `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`

Answer (score 0):

$my_logo = $value[0]['logo'];
echo "";